# How to change color palette of mosaic plot

Tags: r, plot, colors, fill

I have following data and code:

```
> mat <- matrix(c(120,230,84,70,130,83,13,26,18),3)
> dimnames(mat) <- list(c("good","fair","poor"),c("a","b","c"))
> mat

> mat
       a   b  c
good 120  70 13
fair 230 130 26
poor  84  83 18
> 
> chisq.test(mat)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mat
X-squared = 11.411, df = 4, p-value = 0.02231

> library(vcd)
> mosaic(mat, shade=T)
```

[image]

The chi-squared test shows significant difference but no color is seen since residuals are small. With higher residuals, colors are seen:

[image]

?mosaic shows this information:

```
highlighting_fill: color vector or palette function used for a highlighted variable, if any.
```

How can I change fill color for above plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the shading of mosaic plots in `vcd` uses the cut-offs 2 and 4 for the absolute value of the residuals associated with each cell as suggested by Friendly (1994, *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **89**, 190-200). The idea behind this is that these cut-offs should be crossed with approximately 5% and 0.01% if the model fits well (due to the approximate normality of the residuals). However, these cut-offs corresponds to *individual* significance of the cells while the chi-squared test assesses *overall* significance.

There are two strategies to deal with this: (1) As the Friendly (1994) shading is intended to bring out the *pattern* of deviation rather than to correspond directly to *significance*, one can simply modify the cut-offs to lower values that work well for a given table (e.g., 1 and 1.8 here). (2) Switch to a test of the maximum absolute residuals (rather than their sum of squares) so that all cells that are significant at certain significance levels (e.g., 10% and 1%) can be shaded. Both strategies are implemented in `vcd` and illustrated in the examples of `?shading_hcl` (using an example with very similar properties to your `mat`). The underlying ideas are explained in Zeileis, Meyer, Hornik (2007). "Residual-Based Shadings for Visualizing (Conditional) Independence", *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **16**(3), 507-525. [doi:10.1198/106186007X237856](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/106186007X237856)

Strategy (1) can be applied to your data by:

```
mosaic(mat, gp = shading_hcl, gp_args = list(interpolate = c(1, 1.8)))
```

[image: mosaic-hcl]
Strategy (2) is implemented as:

```
set.seed(403)
mosaic(mat, gp = shading_max)
```

[image: mosaic-max]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using both shade=T and gp=shading_max options produces even better color. Can there be some automatic variables instead of c(1,1.8) for gp_args ?

Comment: Setting both `shade = TRUE` and `gp = shading_max` is equivalent to just setting `gp = shading_max`. Note, though, that the maximum test is permutation-based and hence results may change if (as in this case) the results can switch between significant and non-significant (by default judged at 5% level).

Comment: Automatic selection of cut-offs is difficult. The inference-based way is to use the critical values of the maximum statistic as in `shading_max`. The other cut-offs are only heuristics and you could either use other quantiles of the normal distribution, e.g., `qnorm(c(0.85, 0.96))`, or quantiles of the empirical residuals, e.g., `quantile(abs(residuals(chisq.test(mat))), c(0.7, 0.9))`. However, these may or may not lead to useful patterns in the visualization of the mosaic plot. In particular, the latter will _always_ have colored cells, no matter whether there is significance or not.

Answer (score 3):

No really an elegant solution but you can manually define your colours using gpar

```
mosaic(mat, shade=T, colorize = T, gp = gpar(fill=matrix(c("red","blue","light green", "green", "black","red","brown","white","blue"), 3, 3)))
```

The next step is to populate the matrix in gpar with sensible colours. There is a pretty good post here about how to assign a colour ramp based on values.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320940/1502898