# Can't adjust cut-off levels in shading_max

Tags: r

Following on the question on vcd in R by rnso ([How to change color palette of mosaic plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837257/how-to-change-color-palette-of-mosaic-plot))

I would like to ask what I am doing wrong when trying to adjust the cut-off levels in a shading-max mosaic?

```
library(vcd)

mat <- matrix(c(120,230,84,70,130,83,13,26,18),3)
dimnames(mat) <- list(c("good","fair","poor"),c("a","b","c"))
mat

set.seed(403)
mosaic(mat, gp = shading_max)
```

This works fine so far but when trying to modify the (1-alpha) levels nothing happens. It looks the same as when using the default levels (0.9 and 0.99). For example,

```
set.seed(403)
mosaic(mat, gp = shading_max, level = c(0.6, 0.99), n = 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `gp_args`: a list of arguments for the shading-generating function.

```
mosaic(mat, gp = shading_max, 
   gp_args = list(level = c(0.6, 0.99), n = 1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @Marco Sandri

Comment: @user8712408 Please, could you consider to upvote and accept my answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up Thank you