# Cannot get lattice wireframe or cloud to render correctly with colors

Tags: r, lattice

The cloud renders but notice all of the points are blue and they do not match the key.

```
set.seed(7)
d=data.frame(x=runif(1000,1,10),y=runif(1000,1,10))
d$z=d$x+d$y
lattice::cloud(z~x+y,d,drape = TRUE,colorkey = T, scale=list(arrows=F),
               at=quantile(d$z,seq(0,1,length.out =  10)),
               col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("red",'yellow','green'))(10)
               )
lattice::wireframe(z~x+y,d,drape = TRUE,colorkey = T, scale=list(arrows=F),
                   at=quantile(d$z,seq(0,1,length.out =  10)),
                   col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("red",'yellow','green'))(10))
```

[image: blue dots only]

Those blue dots should match the legend on the right.  Any suggestions??

The wireframe doesn't even render a frame...

Comment: `?cloud` says "drape: logical, whether the **wireframe** is to be draped in color.".  And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597134/color-gradient-for-elevation-data-in-a-xyz-plot-with-r-and-lattice) maybe helps you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774777/how-to-change-points-and-add-a-regression-to-a-cloudplot-using-r